# Formatting write protected SD card

Tags: sd-card

Error synchronizing after formatting with type `vfat`:

```
Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Why this error occurs? How can I resolve it?

Comment: What tool are you using to format it ? Try using Gparted.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by write-protected?  Some SD cards come with a switch to put them in read only mode.